# Properties of positive definiteness

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Given two $3 \times 3$ symmetric matrices $A$ and $B$, how do we check the positive definiteness for their combinations:
$-A, A^3, A^8, A+B, A-B, A^{-1} , (A+B)^{-1}.$

Please explain how to derive the answers to above questions for the following cases:
1) $A$ and $B$ both are positive definite
2) None of them is positive definite
3) One of them is positive definite

I am using the Silvester’s criterion of positivity. That is if all eigenvalues are positive, then it is positive definite; negative definite if all eigenvalues are negative and indefinite if some are positive and some negative.

Comment: The cases where only one of the matrices are considered, like $-A$ or $A^3$, are pretty simple: it suffices to consider the effect of the operation on the eigenvalues.

Comment: @Flimpellizieri Just for my clarity- if eigenvalues of A are negative, then A will be negative definite and A square positive definite, right?
Could you answer for combinations of A and B as well?
Thanks?

Comment: Yes, $A^2$ will be positive definite. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, say $Av=\lambda v$, then $A^2v=A(Av)=A(\lambda v)=\lambda Av=\lambda^2 v$. More generally, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $\lambda^k$ is an eigenvalue of $A^k$.

Comment: So that means that a matrix raised to even power will always be positive definite even if it itself is indefinite or negative definite?

Comment: If it is negative definite, yes. But a matrix may have an eigenvalue $0$.